# Make KivyMD android application fit all screen sizes

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

**Goal :**
Make my application fit all android devices

I am trying to build a game using kivy and KivyMD and I don't know how precisely how to make my code fit all android devices.

In the kivyMD documentation, devs use often the "dp" metric (Density-independent Pixels) to describe the size of widgets.

When I use `python3 main.py -m screen:note2,portrait` to view how my app would look like on a note2 with the code below, the layout appears as I would like but the problem occurs when I use a device with a different screen density (say 3 or 1) (https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/modules/screen.py). 8 times out 10 my app look great on a device with a screen density of 2, but for the other screen densities, should I make different versions of my code ?

For example, with screen densities of 2, I could use :

`size: "280dp", "180dp"`

When the density is 1, I could use something like :

`size: "140dp", "90dp"` etc...

I really would like to know what is the correct way to do this. Thanks in advance

main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
Screen:
    MDCard:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: "8dp"
        size_hint: None, None
        #Those dimensions look great when the density is two AND Width of the screen is less than 1920
        size: "280dp", "180dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        MDLabel:
            text: "Title"
            theme_text_color: "Secondary"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
        MDSeparator:
            height: "1dp"
        MDLabel:
            text: "Body"
'''


class TestCard(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


TestCard().run()
```

Comment: Just use `dp` values.